# Strange autoindentation in org mode source blocks

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, python, indentation

I try to use org-mode as a replacement for jupyter notebook, and I was faced with a problem: when I edit a python src block, newlines don't indent properly, so I have to press space 4 times after pressing `RET`.

I checked how the indentation works in elisp src blocks, it also works strange, see gif:
[image]

My org-mode config:

```
(use-package org
  :ensure nil
  :config
  ; (org-babel-jupyter-override-src-block "python")
  (add-hook 'org-babel-after-execute-hook 'org-redisplay-inline-images)
  (add-to-list 'org-structure-template-alist '("p" . "src python"))
  :custom
  (org-startup-indented t)
  (org-startup-with-inline-images t)
  (org-src-tab-acts-natively t)
  (org-src-preserve-indentation nil)
  (org-edit-src-content-indentation 4)
  (org-src-window-setup 'current-window)
  (org-babel-load-languages '((emacs-lisp . t) (python . t))))

(use-package org-superstar
  :hook (org-mode . (lambda () (org-superstar-mode 1))))

(use-package evil-org
  :after (org evil)
  :hook ((org-mode . evil-org-mode)
     (evil-org-mode . (lambda ()
                (evil-org-set-key-theme
                 '(navigation insert textobjects additional calendar))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

### Enter the block before editing it

To get proper indentation and other language features, you have to first enter the OrgSrc block with `org-edit-special`, which is by default bound to <kbd>C-c '</kbd>. See [The Org Manual: Editing Source Code](https://orgmode.org/manual/Editing-Source-Code.html).

Also note you don’t have to type the `#+begin_src` and `#+end_src` manually, you can type `<s` then press <kbd>TAB</kbd>. See [The Org Manual: Structure Templates](https://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-Templates.html).

### Editing inline

If you want to be able to edit code blocks inline while having language features, you may want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61239238/18396947) by malcook, which suggests it is possible with [Polymode](https://polymode.github.io/) `poly-org-mode`. I haven’t tried this myself.

Comment: > You have to first enter the OrgSrc block with org-edit-special, which is by default bound to C-c '.


Of course I can, but I don't want to do it always. It is like to open a text editor every time I edit a cell in Jupyter Notebook (certanly, it's faster but annoying anyway).

Comment: As I know it, there is a setting `org-src-tab-acts-natively`. I thought that it do what I want, but it looks like it don't.

Comment: It allows you to press TAB instead of entering 4 spaces manually, but that is all as far as I know

Comment: Thank you!

I've just tried polymode + poly-org. The indentation works well, but an another problem emerged: the syntax highlighting doesn't work. Maybe I'll make an issue on poly-org github page.